# Managing Django Apps for Inter-related models

Tags: django, django-apps

For Django, the best practice is apparently to have 1 app to do only 1 thing and to do 1 thing right...and so they can be "plugged and played" to other projects

Consider I have a library application and there are 3 apps. `book`, `member` and `loan`. Each of them has their own model.

So in, say `forms.py` in `loan`, I will need to do something like this:

```
from book.models import Book
from member.models import Model
from .models import Loan
#Other key imports

class CreateLoanForm(forms.Form):

    # Some fields

    def save(self):
        # Retrieve fields
        selected_book = self.cleaned_data.get('selected_book')
        selected_member = self.cleaned_data.get('selected_member')
        new_loan = Loan(
            book=Book.objects.get(id=selected_book),
            member=Member.objects.get(id=selected_member),
            date_start=self.cleaned_data.get('date_start'),
            date_end=self.cleaned_data.get('date_end')
        )
```

My questions are:

1. Doesn't the above `from book.models ...` violate the ability to plug and play apps?
2. Is there a better way to import these models? Am I violating best practices when doing so?

Answer (score 0):

For "one app to do one thing, and one thing right" does not mean that it has to have only one model. If you are writing a Library Application then it should have the `book`, `member`, and `loan` models in the same app.

In the context of you question, however, one possible practice to use models from application A in application B would be to define the model as a pluggable setting in app B. See for example what the `auth` module is doing here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model

Comment: Pluggable settings are not at all common practice, unless the model must in fact be pluggable (like the user model), which is the minority of cases. Inter-app dependencies are a reality that you can't get around, and it's better to import the models and have it fail hard and fast if the dependency is missing.

Comment: @knbk, you are correct in that it is not "common" practice and I've updated my answer accordingly. I disagree with the rest of your comment, but it is not in the scope of the answer to argue for/again this method.